# how to control the scene size?

Tags: javascript, three.js, scene

I have set up a test scene where the camera can be moved with the arrow keys, left and right keys rotate on the y axis and up down moves forward or backward on the z axis, makes like driving. Have a ground and sky set up as plains. Problem I got is after I move so far the sky and ground disappear and all I can see is white, like I ran off the scene. Is it possible to make the scene or map area bigger so I can go farther without running off the scene or map.

thanks in advance,

mike.

Comment: Indeed you need a bigger map. Where is the problem applying your solution ?

Comment: how do I make it bigger?

Comment: `mesh.scale(x,y,z)`. Value 1 in x/y/z is the actual value, superior value will increase the size. You can do ground.scale(3,3,3) or sky.scale(40,40,40).
You can also do sky.position=me.position, so you don't need a big skybox and can reduce camera.far (better for depthbuffer).

Comment: this is what i got:'var skyMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0x00bfff} );
  var object = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(20000,20000), skyMaterial);
  object.scale(self.unitSize * 2,self.unitSize * 2,self.unitSize * 2);
  object.position.y = 150;
  object.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;
  object.receiveShadow = true;
  object.updateMatrix();
  object.matrixAutoUpdate = false;' I get this error now "object.scale is not a function".

Comment: I figured it out, thank for the help, PlaneBufferGeometry(Size,Size).

Comment: ok. yes i was wrong : `mesh.scale.set(x,y,z)`